# Дебаг исходного кода сборок в C# без компиляции сборок в dll

Tags: c#, компиляция

У меня есть несколько компонентов(исходный код библиотеки).

Если скомпилировать все сборки, то получится несколько библиотек `dll`
Добавив которые в `references` можно работать с библиотекой.

Как добавить эти сборки в проект, чтобы их не компилировать, а работать с ними как с исходным кодом и можно было дебажить?

**Например:**

- `Library.Assembly1`
- `Library.Assembly2`
- `Library.Assembly3`

Все они как разные проекты в студии идут.

После билда получится 3 `dll` с которыми потом можно работать.

А мне нужно, чтобы эти сборки были в моём проекте и можно было дебажить исходный код.

Comment: добавляешь эти проекты в один solution, и добавляешь reference не на dll. а на проект

Answer (score 4):

1. Добавляешь необходимые проекты в одно решение (Solution).
2. Добавляешь ссылки на свои проекты, там где требуется.  ПКМ по проекту - добавить ссылку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь можно дебажить свои сборки.

---

Порядок сборки можно изменить в зависимостях проектов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если менять исходный код сборок и компилировать их не требуется, тогда нет необходимости добавлять их проекты в решение. Visual Studio позволяет отлаживать исходный код сборки, если она сможет определить путь к соответствующему PDB файлу этой сборки (он содержит отладочную информацию), а так же путь к исходному коду сборки.

Файл PDB создается при компиляции сборки с ключем \debug в той же самой папке, где создается файл сборки (DLL). По умолчанию, компоновщик помещает полный путь и имя связанного PDB-файла в сборку (DLL). При отладке, Visual Studio проверяет, существует ли файл символов в расположении, которое задано в сборке. Но если сборка была скомпилирована не на этом компьютере, то указанного расположения либо не существует, либо PDB файлы находятся не там. В этом случае, путь к PDB файлам можно прописать в настройках (Сервис=>Параметры=>Отладка=>Символы или Tools=>Options=>Debugging=>Symbols).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кроме отладочной информации, PDB файл содержит также сведения о местонахождении исходного кода сборки. Если это местонахождение существует на компьютере, то Visual Studio автоматически открывает соответствующий файл при отладке. Когда отладчик приостанавливает выполнение в месте, для которого отсутствует исходный файл, он отображает страницу *Нет исходного кода* или *Символы не загружены*, которая может помочь найти исходный файл. Это сжатый пересказ инструкции описанной в MSDN: [Указание файлов символов (.pdb) и файлов с исходным кодом в отладчике Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms241613.aspx).

При отладке с помощью PDB файлов, могут возникать трудности с чтением локальных переменных в отладчике. Для избежания этих трудностей, можно сделать две вещи.

1. Отключить главный процесс Visual Studio (Visual Studio Hosting Process).

   - Откройте проект исполняемого файла в Visual Studio. Проекты, которые не создают исполняемые файлы (например, проекты библиотеки классов или службы) не имеют этот параметр.
   - В меню Проект (Project) выберите пункт Свойства (Properties).
   - Перейдите на вкладку Отладка (Debugging).
   - Снимите флажок Разрешить главный процесс Visual Studio (Enable Visual Studio Hosting Process)

Подробнее о побочных эффектах связанных с отключением этой опции написано здесь: [Практическое руководство. Отключение главного процесса](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms185330.aspx)

2. Отключить JIT оптимизацию кода, таким образом избегая несоответствия его источникам, что сильно затрудняет отладку. Это можно сделать при помощи специального ключа в реестре (что влияет на все приложения), но лучше всего запустить Visual Studio из командной строки установив специальную переменную окружения.

> ```
> set COMPLUS_ZapDisable=1 
> cd /d "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\ide\" 
> start devenv.exe 
> exit
> ```

Путь в скрипте выше указывает на Visual Studio 2015. Для другой версии необходимо указать соответствующий номер: VS 2013 - 12.0, VS 2012 - 11.0, VS 2010 - 10.0. Этот трюк позаимствован из блога, в котором он подробно описан: [How to disable optimizations when debugging Reference Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sburke/2008/01/29/how-to-disable-optimizations-when-debugging-reference-source/).